# JHipster-Angular 5: using service from another module ends up with Status Code: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: angular, service, lazy-loading, jhipster

I was trying to reuse an existing (generated) service for one of the entities, from within another Lazy-Loaded feature module.

What I did was to just import the module containing the service in the feature module.
e.g.

```
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [ 
        Module1,
        Module2,
        ServiceModule 
    ]
})
```

While in **ServiceModule** there is the following:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        MyService
    ]
})
```

But when injecting **MyService** in a component inside my LazyLoadedModule
using one of its methods gives me the Status Code: 401 Unauthorized.
The authentication method used is JWT tokens, which are handled by JHipster default code, by storing them in the browser.
The service does a simple get all call to the back-end API, which I tested with postman and it's working fine.

All of this doesn't happen if I use a service within the lazy loaded module. Any idea of what's missing here?

Comment: The missing thing first is your description. What does you service is meant to do ? Is there anything (token, credentials) that you service uses ? Tell us more. And the 401 status code is not due to your angular app I think. It should be the server response.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this problem, was the lack of **http-interceptors** in the **feature-module**.
The http-interceptors I'm refferring are the same used in the **app.module**. So, what fixed this was to copy and paste the following code from app.module.ts to feature.moduele.ts

```
providers: [ 
        { 
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
            useClass: AuthInterceptor, 
            multi: true, 
            deps: [ 
                LocalStorageService, 
                SessionStorageService 
            ] 
        }, 
        { 
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
            useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor, 
            multi: true, 
            deps: [ 
                Injector 
            ] 
        }, 
        { 
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
            useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor, 
            multi: true, 
            deps: [ 
                JhiEventManager 
            ] 
        }, 
        { 
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
            useClass: NotificationInterceptor, 
            multi: true, 
            deps: [ 
                Injector 
            ] 
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I am using Jhipster 4.5 and it was approximately the same solution for me.
In the appModule providers, there was a ```customHttpProvider(),``` that I had to copy in the lazy-loaded module providers in order to work.
Thanks for the help.